# Production .NET Core web api returns html instead of json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In a .NET Core 3.1+Angular application I have one api that returns html of main page instead of json.code result is 200/OK
strange is in development tests works fine.
I've created request from Postman,Talend API Tester but same results

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("/api/app/libr/{d1}/{d2}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetLibr(string d1, string d2)
            {
                var errMs = "";
    
                if (d1.Length != 8 || d2.Length != 8)
                    errMs = "invalid data";
    
                if (errMs != "")
                    return BadRequest(errMs);
    
                var query = db.Set<SpHT_CAMLIB>()
                  .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM HT_CAMLIB({0},{1})", d1,d2)
                  .AsQueryable();
    
                return Ok(
                    await query.Select(c => new
                    {
                        c.ID,
                        c.NAME,
                        c.TIP,
                        c.ZON,
                        c.IDTA
                    }
                       )
                       .OrderBy(c => c.ZON)
                       .ThenBy(c => c.ID)
                       .ToListAsync()
                       );
            }
```

Comment: the server is returning an error page, look at the returned HTML  to see what the issue is

Comment: code result is 200/Ok,I see no error in it

Comment: here is returned page: https://pastebin.com/raWfn8V9

Comment: Sounds like .net core is handing out angular page without angular processing it.  Make sure you have all the dependencies are up for angular and .net core and running in the environment where ever this fails.  In the test environment, you have everything in one place (i.e. your pc or laptop) but that may not be the case in other environments.

Comment: production app works without problems,only calling api from outside fails,did not understand what I should do

Comment: Move all the code inside of OK method and give it a name. Put in a log for that value. The result will be nothing because the query returned nothing.

Comment: Indeed there was a  conversion error,I've installed Serilog and got: "System.FormatException: String '31/05/2022' was not recognized as a valid DateTime." fixed using DateTime.ParseExact